# $request->user()->role errror - trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am in the process of creating a middleware which will handle authorization say check role then authorize. But when i am doing `$role = $request->user()->role;`

It is giving me error `Trying to get property of non-object`. What I am doing wrong here.

Here is the extract of my Middleware class

RoleMiddleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, $next) {
    $role = $request->user()->role;
```

Also I would like to know the difference and would like to know which is best, should I authorize using Middleware, Polices or gate facade ?

Help is appreciated,

Thanks,
Sambhav

Comment: are you sure all the users have a role ?

Comment: Yes they are in DB and I am also fetching them in one of my controller from `$request->user()->role`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "best" way method to authorize users. You can use Middleware, Policies or Gate or mix them together.

In your case the problem is:

```
$role = $request->user()->role;
```

because user is not always logged in.

So you should change it like so:

```
$role = $request->user() ? $request->user()->role: 'guest';
```

to set `guest` role for not logged user and to get rid of error.

Comment: Cool, Thank you Marcin :)